# Disconnect from Microsoft Team meeting using Ubuntu 22.04 Citrix workspace 2207 + HDX

Tags: citrix, microsoft-teams

Environment

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- Citrix Workspace app 2207 for Linux GA
- HDX RealTime Media Engine 2.9.500 for Microsoft Skype® for Business

Symptom

Microsoft Team meeting via Citrix app constantly got disconnected.
Peer to Peer call works fine

Checked various logs and unable to identify the root cause for disconnection.

Ubuntu 20.04 + libunwind-12 does not seem to have issue with MS-Teams meeting.

Did anyone run into similar issue before?  Any help appreciated.